# What's the difference between 说话的人 and 说话人?

Tags: meaning

Does anyone know the difference between 说话的人 and 说话人?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can consider "说话人" as a noun equivalent to "speaker" (發言人/者). "说话的人" is a phrase that means "the person who is (currently) speaking/talking" or "the person making the talk".

Comment: Yes "说话人 does sound like a noun; When it means "the one who speaks", 说话的人 and 说话人 (with 的 omitted ) are both acceptable, the only difference is 说话的人 is more colloquial.

Answer (score 1):

No difference, really. The speaker, the person who speaks/spoke/is speaking/was speaking/will be speaking....

说话人 is a tad closer to written form and 说话的人 more colloquial, but only marginally. Sometimes the context might favour one over the other simply because it sounds better to a native ear. If you share with us where you found these two usages, that might shed some light.

Comment: Yes, when it means "the one who speaks", 说话的人 and 说话人 (with 的 omitted ) are both acceptable, the only difference is 说话的人 is more colloquial. But r13 does has a point,  "说话人 does sound like a noun and could be used as one

Comment: I am not sure I am getting it. I thought they are both nouns (or noun phrases). Perhaps some examples may help?

Comment: Doesn't 说话人 sound similar to 發言人? Which is commonly used as a 'title'  for 'speaker' Maybe I should say "说话人" can be a  'title noun (speaker)' or 'The person who speaks (noun with an adjectival verb attached)'

Comment: 说话人 (the one who speaks/ the speaker) reminds me of  話事人 (the one who decides matter / the boss)  in Cantonese

Comment: @TangHo Do you mean 發言人 (spokesperson)? I have not heard of 说话人 used to refer to a spokesperson. Is it commonly used and is it regional?

Comment: The structure of [说话(v)+人(n)] is similar to [發言(v)人(n)]. I said it sounds like a 'title noun' but it really isn't (unlike 發言人)